# Change the MIME type in WordPress

Tags: php, video, wordpress, jwplayer

I am using JW Player plugin from wordpress. I try to upload mp4 file in the admin dashboard -> media 
There is nothing problem in the uploading. but when i try to load the video in jw player of wordpress it loads only audio. When i try to upload the file it shows the mime type as 
video/quicktime but i uploaded the mp4 file and mime type should be video/mp4 Not sure why this should happen.

Here is the screenshot that i uploaded from my side

[image]

How to change the mime type as video/mp4. Is that anything in wordpress or in convertor?

Any one give me a suggestion to overcome this problem

Reg,
vicky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add additional MIME types, in function.php write the below code:

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'add_custom_mime_types');

function add_custom_mime_types($mimes) {
    return array_merge($mimes, array (
        'ac3' => 'audio/ac3',
        'mpa' => 'audio/MPA',
        'flv' => 'video/x-flv',
        'svg' => 'image/svg+xml'
    ));
}
```

To remove existing MIME types:

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'remove_mime_types');

function remove_mime_types($mimes) {
    unset($mimes['mp4']);
}
```

Comment: Hi Arshad thanks for your answer, I don't have any problem on uploading corresponding mime type but my question is i am uploading mp4 file only but mime type comes video/quicktime not video/mp4

Comment: add 'mp4' => 'video/mp4', unset( $mimes['mov'] ); Try it and let me know what happened?

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the video/mp4 mime type via .htaccess

Sample:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  AddType video/ogg .ogv
  AddType video/webm .webm
  AddType video/mp4 .mp4
</IfModule>
```